# How do I remove all strings containing digits before "hs" like "18hs" from a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a list of strings such as:

```
["hello","18hs","18aaa","21hr"]
```

how do I remove all strings that match any digits plus `"hs"` or `"h"` or `"hr"`?

Note: I don't want to lose any string ending in "h" like "fish".

desired output: `["hello,"18aaa"]`

I knew it could be done by regex, but I couldn't set the capture group properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ["hello", "18hs", "18aaa", "21hr"]
>>> [w for w in words if not re.match(r'\d+h', w)]
['hello', '18aaa']
```

This loops over the list and keeps the items that don't match the regex `\d+h`, which means "one or more digits followed by an h".

If you need to keep strings like `7hg`, use a more specific regex, `\d+h(s|r)?$`, which means "one or more digits, h, optional s or r, end of string":

```
>>> words = ["hello", "18hs", "18aaa", "21hr", '7hg']
>>> [w for w in words if not re.match(r'\d+h(s|r)?$', w)]
['hello', '18aaa', '7hg']
```

Also note that `re.match` automatically matches the start of the string, so it's like an implicit `^` at the start of the regex.

Comment: thank you! this was what I was looking for. I'm a bit of a newbie...

Comment: According to the requirements, the regex should read `^\d+h(s|r)?$`.

Comment: @Flinsch Good point, though the requirements are vague. I've added that in.

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through them
- Check if there are any matches for this regex: `(\d+h)`
- If so, remove element
- Else don't

Pretty simple stuff.

Comment: The pattern `[hr|h|hs]` will match one character out of the set of `h`, `r`, `s`, and `|`. Also, the parentheses around `\d+` don't do anything.

Comment: The regex could be simplified to `\d+h`

Comment: Both of you are correct, I'll adjust the answer - thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple if you use list filters + lambdas like so:

```
my_list = ["hello","18hs","18aaa","21hr"] # input data

custom_filters = [lambda x: not x.endswith('hr'),  
                  lambda x: not x.endswith('hs'), 
                  lambda x: not x.endswith('h')] # define custom filters

final = list(filter(lambda x: all([custom_filter(x) for custom_filter in custom_filters]), my_list)) # apply custom filters one by one

# should result in ["hello", "18aaa"]
```